# cakephp getLastInsertID()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, last-insert-id

This code:

```
foreach ($arrays as $array){
    $this->Model->set('bla', $array['key1']);
    $this->Model->set('alb', $array['key2']);
    $this->Model->save();
    echo $this->Model->getLastInsertID() . ",";
}
```

returns:

```
2,2
```

should return:

```
1,2
```

I tried using

```
foreach ($arrays as $array){
    $this->Model->query('insert....');
    $this->Model->query('select last_insert_id()')
    }
```

but that returned "1,1"...
So what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: try  $this->Model->set('id', '');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving inside a loop, you need to explicitly call Model::create() first.

```
foreach ($arrays as $array){
    $this->Model->create();
    $this->Model->set('bla', $array['key1']);
    $this->Model->set('alb', $array['key2']);
    $this->Model->save();
    echo $this->Model->getLastInsertID() . ",";
}
```

Comment: Somehow I didnt think of it :D ... Thanks... Should have asked first... I would save a lot of time and keyboards.

Comment: Thanks for the create() tip, I was struggling a lot and I was finally able to solve the problem thanks to that method.